# How do I combine predictions of four Poisson regressions that use the same independent variable?

Tags: predictive-models, spatial, poisson-regression

**Question**: I have a large area, $N_{total}$, where I decomposed spatially into smaller $i$ squares (northwest, northeast, southwest, and southeast quadrants) and ran Poisson regression on these four squares individually using the same independent variable $X$ (time series). How do I combine the four squares $N_{i}$ into one predictive model $N_{total}$?

[image]

Specifically, I want to combine $N_{NW}$, $N_{NE}$, $N_{SE}$, $N_{SW}$ so that $N_{total} = N_{NW} + N_{NE} + N_{SE} + N_{SW}$ where each square is represented as these regression equations:

$ln(N_{NW}) = 0.5X + 2$

$ln(N_{NE}) = -0.5X + 2$

$ln(N_{SE}) = -0.5X - 2$

$ln(N_{SW}) = 0.5X - 2$

So I can have a total event count for the entire square (all four regions)? In other words, I want to add up the four predictive time series and compare with observation of whole square.

**Problem**: When I try to combine the four squares by adding the four region's predictions, the correlation between predicted and observed is essentially zero with hardly any variance compared to $N_{total}$ observation. Specifically, I believe the opposing regression coefficients and intercepts effectively cancel each other out when summing $N_i$ up. The reason I decompose into four quadrants and then run regression separately instead of running the regression on the larger square is because the dependent variable affects $N_i$ differently as depicted by the sign of the regression coefficient.

Apologies in advance if this question is duplicated, but I couldn't find a similar question that answered for me. Please forgive my limited stats background.

**Edit:** Below is the actual data whereas the above example is a simplified case. The code lists four regions in four separate data.frames where the predictor is the El Nino Southern Oscillation (enso) and the predictand is tropical cyclone genesis (counts/season).

```r
library(ggplot2)

### Setting up the four quadrants
genesis_nw <- data.frame(year = rep(1979:2020),
                         count = c(1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 5, 4, 0, 0, 8, 3, 3, 1, 3, 0, 4,
                                   1, 4, 1, 0, 4, 6, 4, 4, 0, 4, 5, 3, 3, 8, 3, 2,
                                   3, 4, 3, 0, 0, 6, 3, 4, 2, 6),
                         enso = c(0.106782586666667,-0.100661988333333,-0.30497886,1.23395135,
                                  -0.0206650233333333,-0.783736333333333,-0.536327,0.353983466666667,
                                  1.32786416666667,-1.68626066666667,-0.529311483333333,0.110523433333333,
                                  0.752194033333333,-0.0461701333333333,0.284597495,0.3661777,
                                  -0.6096041,-0.3822457,2.22369,-0.96646625,-1.13437595,
                                  -0.604320066666667,-0.243592266666667,0.904357516666667,
                                  0.15169184,0.358386541666667,-0.0529826766666667,0.505672478333333,
                                  -1.03634665,-0.12731812,0.79725065,-1.275762,-0.633416416666667,
                                  0.340000951666667,-0.39648495,0.41396485,2.15219966666667,
                                  -0.478576938333333,-0.26552895,0.419404183333333,0.241118271666667,-0.827966683333333))

genesis_ne <- data.frame(year = rep(1979:2020),
                         count = c(0,3,0,2,1,0,1,5,5,2,2,2,3,4,3,5,2,5,4,0,2,1,2,7,
                                   2,2,0,1,1,1,2,0,0,0,2,1,6,4,1,4,3,0),
                         enso = c(0.106782586666667,-0.100661988333333,-0.30497886,1.23395135,
                                  -0.0206650233333333,-0.783736333333333,-0.536327,0.353983466666667,
                                  1.32786416666667,-1.68626066666667,-0.529311483333333,0.110523433333333,
                                  0.752194033333333,-0.0461701333333333,0.284597495,0.3661777,
                                  -0.6096041,-0.3822457,2.22369,-0.96646625,-1.13437595,
                                  -0.604320066666667,-0.243592266666667,0.904357516666667,
                                  0.15169184,0.358386541666667,-0.0529826766666667,0.505672478333333,
                                  -1.03634665,-0.12731812,0.79725065,-1.275762,-0.633416416666667,
                                  0.340000951666667,-0.39648495,0.41396485,2.15219966666667,
                                  -0.478576938333333,-0.26552895,0.419404183333333,0.241118271666667,-0.827966683333333))

genesis_se <- data.frame(year = rep(1979:2020),
                         count = c(6,7,6,5,8,6,5,10,5,2,5,9,10,11,11,9,7,8,12,
                                   1,0,2,3,5,5,7,2,4,1,0,4,0,2,3,4,5,6,0,1,5,5,1),
                         enso = c(0.106782586666667,-0.100661988333333,-0.30497886,1.23395135,
                                  -0.0206650233333333,-0.783736333333333,-0.536327,0.353983466666667,
                                  1.32786416666667,-1.68626066666667,-0.529311483333333,0.110523433333333,
                                  0.752194033333333,-0.0461701333333333,0.284597495,0.3661777,
                                  -0.6096041,-0.3822457,2.22369,-0.96646625,-1.13437595,
                                  -0.604320066666667,-0.243592266666667,0.904357516666667,
                                  0.15169184,0.358386541666667,-0.0529826766666667,0.505672478333333,
                                  -1.03634665,-0.12731812,0.79725065,-1.275762,-0.633416416666667,
                                  0.340000951666667,-0.39648495,0.41396485,2.15219966666667,
                                  -0.478576938333333,-0.26552895,0.419404183333333,0.241118271666667,-0.827966683333333))

genesis_sw <- data.frame(year = rep(1979:2020),
                         count = c(11,7,12,12,12,15,11,7,11,11,14,15,12,13,13,13,12,12,8,14,12,14,15,7,11,10,
                                   12,11,15,12,12,12,10,14,20,10,8,15,18,13,14,15),
                         enso = c(0.106782586666667,-0.100661988333333,-0.30497886,1.23395135,
                                  -0.0206650233333333,-0.783736333333333,-0.536327,0.353983466666667,
                                  1.32786416666667,-1.68626066666667,-0.529311483333333,0.110523433333333,
                                  0.752194033333333,-0.0461701333333333,0.284597495,0.3661777,
                                  -0.6096041,-0.3822457,2.22369,-0.96646625,-1.13437595,
                                  -0.604320066666667,-0.243592266666667,0.904357516666667,
                                  0.15169184,0.358386541666667,-0.0529826766666667,0.505672478333333,
                                  -1.03634665,-0.12731812,0.79725065,-1.275762,-0.633416416666667,
                                  0.340000951666667,-0.39648495,0.41396485,2.15219966666667,
                                  -0.478576938333333,-0.26552895,0.419404183333333,0.241118271666667,-0.827966683333333))

### Poisson regressions
genesis_nw_poisson <- glm(count ~ enso, data = genesis_nw, family= "poisson")
genesis_ne_poisson <- glm(count ~ enso, data = genesis_ne, family= "poisson")
genesis_se_poisson <- glm(count ~ enso, data = genesis_se, family= "poisson")
genesis_sw_poisson <- glm(count ~ enso, data = genesis_sw, family= "poisson")

### Predict
predict <- data.frame(year = genesis_sw$year,
                  total = genesis_nw$count+genesis_ne$count+genesis_se$count+genesis_sw$count,
                  nw_count = genesis_nw$count, ne_count = genesis_ne$count,
                  sw_count = genesis_sw$count, se_count = genesis_se$count)

predict$nw_count_predict <- exp(predict(genesis_nw_poisson, newdata = data.frame(genesis_nw)))
predict$ne_count_predict <- exp(predict(genesis_ne_poisson, newdata = data.frame(genesis_ne)))
predict$se_count_predict <- exp(predict(genesis_se_poisson, newdata = data.frame(genesis_se)))
predict$sw_count_predict <- exp(predict(genesis_sw_poisson, newdata = data.frame(genesis_sw)))

predict$total_predict <- predict$nw_count_predict+predict$ne_count_predict+predict$se_count_predict+predict$sw_count_predict

### plot predict vs observation
ggplot(predict, aes(x=year)) +
  geom_line(aes(y=nw_count_predict), color = "red") +
  geom_line(aes(y=nw_count), color = "black") +
  labs(x = "NW TC count", y = "Season")

ggplot(predict, aes(x=year)) +
  geom_line(aes(y=ne_count_predict), color = "red") +
  geom_line(aes(y=ne_count), color = "black") +
  labs(x = "NE TC count", y = "Season")

ggplot(predict, aes(x=year)) +
  geom_line(aes(y=se_count_predict), color = "red") +
  geom_line(aes(y=se_count), color = "black") +
  labs(x = "SE TC count", y = "Season")

ggplot(predict, aes(x=year)) +
  geom_line(aes(y=sw_count_predict), color = "red") +
  geom_line(aes(y=sw_count), color = "black") +
  labs(x = "SW TC count", y = "Season")

### Plotting total
ggplot(predict, aes(x=year)) +
  geom_line(aes(y=total_predict), color = "red") +
  geom_line(aes(y=total), color = "black") +
  labs(x = "Total TC count", y = "Season")
```

Here are the plots from the code. Red is predicted. Black is observed.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
And the total...
[image]

Comment: It is unclear that "correlation" is a suitable way to measure the prediction quality.  For instance, if you have predictions consistently close to 1000 and actual values consistently close to 1000 you're probably doing extremely well even though the correlation between predicted and actual could be zero (or even negative!).  It would help to know more about the kinds and amounts of data you have as well as the actual results you are getting.

Comment: @whuber Hi thanks for the suggestions and thoughts. I made an edit to include reproducible code.

Comment: The equations are wrong for Poisson regression; the left hand side of those equations should involve parameters of the distribution of the response variables, not the response variables themselves.

Comment: Why split up the area?  Why can't you just model $N_{total}$ rather than the components?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**glm Solution:**

As Demetri said above, you are dealing with a multinomial problem but fortunately there is a way to model multinomial data using Poisson distribution. It's called ***Poisson Trick***! (details here: [On the “Poisson Trick” and its Extensions
for Fitting Multinomial Regression Models](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1707.08538.pdf))

To model the Multinomial data with Poisson you need to slightly change your data structure to make sure you bind the counts from different regions together. So this is how you can do it with glm:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
### Setting up the four quadrants
genesis_nw <- data.frame(year = rep(1979:2020),
                         NW = c(1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 5, 4, 0, 0, 8, 3, 3, 1, 3, 0, 4,
                                   1, 4, 1, 0, 4, 6, 4, 4, 0, 4, 5, 3, 3, 8, 3, 2,
                                   3, 4, 3, 0, 0, 6, 3, 4, 2, 6),
                         enso = c(0.106782586666667,-0.100661988333333,-0.30497886,1.23395135,
                                  -0.0206650233333333,-0.783736333333333,-0.536327,0.353983466666667,
                                  1.32786416666667,-1.68626066666667,-0.529311483333333,0.110523433333333,
                                  0.752194033333333,-0.0461701333333333,0.284597495,0.3661777,
                                  -0.6096041,-0.3822457,2.22369,-0.96646625,-1.13437595,
                                  -0.604320066666667,-0.243592266666667,0.904357516666667,
                                  0.15169184,0.358386541666667,-0.0529826766666667,0.505672478333333,
                                  -1.03634665,-0.12731812,0.79725065,-1.275762,-0.633416416666667,
                                  0.340000951666667,-0.39648495,0.41396485,2.15219966666667,
                                  -0.478576938333333,-0.26552895,0.419404183333333,0.241118271666667,-0.827966683333333))

genesis_ne <- data.frame(year = rep(1979:2020),
                         enso = c(0.106782586666667,-0.100661988333333,-0.30497886,1.23395135,
                                  -0.0206650233333333,-0.783736333333333,-0.536327,0.353983466666667,
                                  1.32786416666667,-1.68626066666667,-0.529311483333333,0.110523433333333,
                                  0.752194033333333,-0.0461701333333333,0.284597495,0.3661777,
                                  -0.6096041,-0.3822457,2.22369,-0.96646625,-1.13437595,
                                  -0.604320066666667,-0.243592266666667,0.904357516666667,
                                  0.15169184,0.358386541666667,-0.0529826766666667,0.505672478333333,
                                  -1.03634665,-0.12731812,0.79725065,-1.275762,-0.633416416666667,
                                  0.340000951666667,-0.39648495,0.41396485,2.15219966666667,
                                  -0.478576938333333,-0.26552895,0.419404183333333,0.241118271666667,-0.827966683333333),
                         
                         NE = c(0,3,0,2,1,0,1,5,5,2,2,2,3,4,3,5,2,5,4,0,2,1,2,7,
                                      2,2,0,1,1,1,2,0,0,0,2,1,6,4,1,4,3,0))

genesis_se <- data.frame(year = rep(1979:2020),
                         SE = c(6,7,6,5,8,6,5,10,5,2,5,9,10,11,11,9,7,8,12,
                                   1,0,2,3,5,5,7,2,4,1,0,4,0,2,3,4,5,6,0,1,5,5,1),
                         enso = c(0.106782586666667,-0.100661988333333,-0.30497886,1.23395135,
                                  -0.0206650233333333,-0.783736333333333,-0.536327,0.353983466666667,
                                  1.32786416666667,-1.68626066666667,-0.529311483333333,0.110523433333333,
                                  0.752194033333333,-0.0461701333333333,0.284597495,0.3661777,
                                  -0.6096041,-0.3822457,2.22369,-0.96646625,-1.13437595,
                                  -0.604320066666667,-0.243592266666667,0.904357516666667,
                                  0.15169184,0.358386541666667,-0.0529826766666667,0.505672478333333,
                                  -1.03634665,-0.12731812,0.79725065,-1.275762,-0.633416416666667,
                                  0.340000951666667,-0.39648495,0.41396485,2.15219966666667,
                                  -0.478576938333333,-0.26552895,0.419404183333333,0.241118271666667,-0.827966683333333))

genesis_sw <- data.frame(year = rep(1979:2020),
                         SW = c(11,7,12,12,12,15,11,7,11,11,14,15,12,13,13,13,12,12,8,14,12,14,15,7,11,10,
                                   12,11,15,12,12,12,10,14,20,10,8,15,18,13,14,15),
                         enso = c(0.106782586666667,-0.100661988333333,-0.30497886,1.23395135,
                                  -0.0206650233333333,-0.783736333333333,-0.536327,0.353983466666667,
                                  1.32786416666667,-1.68626066666667,-0.529311483333333,0.110523433333333,
                                  0.752194033333333,-0.0461701333333333,0.284597495,0.3661777,
                                  -0.6096041,-0.3822457,2.22369,-0.96646625,-1.13437595,
                                  -0.604320066666667,-0.243592266666667,0.904357516666667,
                                  0.15169184,0.358386541666667,-0.0529826766666667,0.505672478333333,
                                  -1.03634665,-0.12731812,0.79725065,-1.275762,-0.633416416666667,
                                  0.340000951666667,-0.39648495,0.41396485,2.15219966666667,
                                  -0.478576938333333,-0.26552895,0.419404183333333,0.241118271666667,-0.827966683333333))

####################### glm SOLUTION ######################################
df_merged <- list(genesis_ne, genesis_se, genesis_sw, genesis_nw) %>% reduce(left_join)

# Pivotting the dataframe from wide to long to use the "Poisson Trick" 
df_long <- df_merged %>% 
  mutate(id = as.factor(seq(1,nrow(.),1))) %>% #This is important to glue the counts
  pivot_longer(names_to = "location",
               values_to = "count",
               -c(id, year, enso))

glm.fit <- glm(count ~ id + location + enso*location , data = df_long, family= "poisson")
df_long$preds <- predict(glm.fit, newdata = df_long, type = "response")
```

Now let's plot the fitted values and make sure they properly add up:

```r
# Plotting Fitted versus observed
df_long %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_line(aes(x = year, y = count)) +
  geom_line(aes(x = year, y = preds), color = "red") +
  geom_abline() +
  facet_grid(location ~ .)

# Check to see if the N_totals match 
df_long %>% 
  group_by(year) %>% 
  summarise(count = sum(count),
            preds = sum(preds)) %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_line(aes(year, count)) +
  geom_line(aes(year, preds), color = "red", alpha = 0.5) +
  ggtitle("Checking N_total")
```

[image: pic1]
[image: pic2]

Comment: Interesting result, and yes, this solves the issue. I wasn't aware of the Poisson trick. After applying the Poisson trick, the model shows 49 coefficients. Is it possible to apply this in a predictive framework with new data? As the coefficients are tied to the ids, would applying new data using the `predict()` function be misleading? Thank you again, and so sorry for taking so long to respond.

Answer (score 10):

## Let's Think About Restrictions

If you want to the predictions of each quadrant to sum to the total, you have to incorporate that restriction into the model.  Presently, there is nothing relating the 4 regressions and hence there is no requirement that the restriction be satisfied.

Consider an alternative model.  The total at timestep $i$ is

$$ N_{total, i} = \sum_j  \mathbf{q}_{j, i}$$

We can think of the four quadrants at the $i^{th}$ timestep as a vector (call it $\mathbf{q}_i$) constrained to sum to $N_{total,i}$.  Hence, it may be plausible to consider the count in each quadrants as a draw from a multinomial distribution

$$\mathbf{q}_i \sim \operatorname{Multinomial}({\theta}_i)$$

Here, $\theta_i$ is the multinomial parameter.  It is a vector in which the components sum to 1.  Each component of $\theta_i$ can be comprised of a regression on enso for each quadrant, and then forced to sum to 1 using a softmax function.  Hence, the $j^{th}$ component of $\theta_i$ would be

$$ \theta_{j, i} = \dfrac{e^{X_i\beta_j}}{\sum_j e^{X_i\beta_j}}$$

Here $\beta_j$ is a vector of regression coefficients, one for each quadrant, and $X_i$ is the $i^{th}$ row of a design matrix (basically a matrix with a column of 1s and whatever other variables you want to regress on).

This is quite the model.  Let's recapitulate the model here for posterity.  Remember, $i$ is the time step.

## The Model

$$ N_{total, i} = \sum_j  \mathbf{q}_{j, i}$$

$$\mathbf{q}_i \sim \operatorname{Multinomial}({\theta}_i)$$

$$ \theta_{j, i} = \dfrac{e^{X_i\beta_j}}{\sum_j e^{X_i\beta_j}}$$

I'm not sure how to fit this in a frequentist framework, but we can use MCMC and Stan to fit this in a Bayesian framework.

## A Stan Model

```r
model_code = "
data{
int N;
int quadrants[N, 4];
matrix[N, 2] X;
}
parameters{
  vector[2] beta_ne;
  vector[2] beta_nw;
  vector[2] beta_se;
  vector[2] beta_sw;
}
transformed parameters{
  vector[N] theta_ne = X*beta_ne;
  vector[N] theta_nw = X*beta_nw;
  vector[N] theta_se = X*beta_se;
  vector[N] theta_sw = X*beta_sw;
  matrix[4, N]  theta;
  
  for(i in 1:N){
    theta[:, i] = softmax([theta_ne[i], theta_nw[i], theta_se[i], theta_sw[i]]');
  }

}
model{
  beta_ne ~ std_normal();
  beta_nw ~ std_normal();
  beta_se ~ std_normal();
  beta_sw ~ std_normal();
  
  for(i in 1:N){
  quadrants[i] ~ multinomial(theta[:,i]);
  }
}
generated quantities{
  
  int quad_ppc[4, N];
  for(i in 1:N){
    quad_ppc[:,i] = multinomial_rng(theta[:,i], sum(quadrants[i]));
  }

}
"
```

Let's massage some of the data you've posted so we can use it with Stan

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(cmdstanr)
library(tidybayes)
### Setting up the four quadrants
genesis_nw <- data.frame(year = rep(1979:2020),
                         count = c(1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 5, 4, 0, 0, 8, 3, 3, 1, 3, 0, 4,
                                   1, 4, 1, 0, 4, 6, 4, 4, 0, 4, 5, 3, 3, 8, 3, 2,
                                   3, 4, 3, 0, 0, 6, 3, 4, 2, 6),
                         enso = c(0.106782586666667,-0.100661988333333,-0.30497886,1.23395135,
                                  -0.0206650233333333,-0.783736333333333,-0.536327,0.353983466666667,
                                  1.32786416666667,-1.68626066666667,-0.529311483333333,0.110523433333333,
                                  0.752194033333333,-0.0461701333333333,0.284597495,0.3661777,
                                  -0.6096041,-0.3822457,2.22369,-0.96646625,-1.13437595,
                                  -0.604320066666667,-0.243592266666667,0.904357516666667,
                                  0.15169184,0.358386541666667,-0.0529826766666667,0.505672478333333,
                                  -1.03634665,-0.12731812,0.79725065,-1.275762,-0.633416416666667,
                                  0.340000951666667,-0.39648495,0.41396485,2.15219966666667,
                                  -0.478576938333333,-0.26552895,0.419404183333333,0.241118271666667,-0.827966683333333),
                         quadrant = 'nw')

genesis_ne <- data.frame(year = rep(1979:2020),
                         count = c(0,3,0,2,1,0,1,5,5,2,2,2,3,4,3,5,2,5,4,0,2,1,2,7,
                                   2,2,0,1,1,1,2,0,0,0,2,1,6,4,1,4,3,0),
                         enso = c(0.106782586666667,-0.100661988333333,-0.30497886,1.23395135,
                                  -0.0206650233333333,-0.783736333333333,-0.536327,0.353983466666667,
                                  1.32786416666667,-1.68626066666667,-0.529311483333333,0.110523433333333,
                                  0.752194033333333,-0.0461701333333333,0.284597495,0.3661777,
                                  -0.6096041,-0.3822457,2.22369,-0.96646625,-1.13437595,
                                  -0.604320066666667,-0.243592266666667,0.904357516666667,
                                  0.15169184,0.358386541666667,-0.0529826766666667,0.505672478333333,
                                  -1.03634665,-0.12731812,0.79725065,-1.275762,-0.633416416666667,
                                  0.340000951666667,-0.39648495,0.41396485,2.15219966666667,
                                  -0.478576938333333,-0.26552895,0.419404183333333,0.241118271666667,-0.827966683333333),
                         quadrant = 'ne')

genesis_se <- data.frame(year = rep(1979:2020),
                         count = c(6,7,6,5,8,6,5,10,5,2,5,9,10,11,11,9,7,8,12,
                                   1,0,2,3,5,5,7,2,4,1,0,4,0,2,3,4,5,6,0,1,5,5,1),
                         enso = c(0.106782586666667,-0.100661988333333,-0.30497886,1.23395135,
                                  -0.0206650233333333,-0.783736333333333,-0.536327,0.353983466666667,
                                  1.32786416666667,-1.68626066666667,-0.529311483333333,0.110523433333333,
                                  0.752194033333333,-0.0461701333333333,0.284597495,0.3661777,
                                  -0.6096041,-0.3822457,2.22369,-0.96646625,-1.13437595,
                                  -0.604320066666667,-0.243592266666667,0.904357516666667,
                                  0.15169184,0.358386541666667,-0.0529826766666667,0.505672478333333,
                                  -1.03634665,-0.12731812,0.79725065,-1.275762,-0.633416416666667,
                                  0.340000951666667,-0.39648495,0.41396485,2.15219966666667,
                                  -0.478576938333333,-0.26552895,0.419404183333333,0.241118271666667,-0.827966683333333), 
                         quadrant = 'se')

genesis_sw <- data.frame(year = rep(1979:2020),
                         count = c(11,7,12,12,12,15,11,7,11,11,14,15,12,13,13,13,12,12,8,14,12,14,15,7,11,10,
                                   12,11,15,12,12,12,10,14,20,10,8,15,18,13,14,15),
                         enso = c(0.106782586666667,-0.100661988333333,-0.30497886,1.23395135,
                                  -0.0206650233333333,-0.783736333333333,-0.536327,0.353983466666667,
                                  1.32786416666667,-1.68626066666667,-0.529311483333333,0.110523433333333,
                                  0.752194033333333,-0.0461701333333333,0.284597495,0.3661777,
                                  -0.6096041,-0.3822457,2.22369,-0.96646625,-1.13437595,
                                  -0.604320066666667,-0.243592266666667,0.904357516666667,
                                  0.15169184,0.358386541666667,-0.0529826766666667,0.505672478333333,
                                  -1.03634665,-0.12731812,0.79725065,-1.275762,-0.633416416666667,
                                  0.340000951666667,-0.39648495,0.41396485,2.15219966666667,
                                  -0.478576938333333,-0.26552895,0.419404183333333,0.241118271666667,-0.827966683333333),
                         quadrant = 'sw')

data = bind_rows(genesis_ne, genesis_nw, genesis_se, genesis_sw)

d = spread(data, quadrant, count) %>% 
    mutate(total = ne + nw + se + sw)

model_data = list(
  N = nrow(d),
  quadrants = d %>% select(ne, nw, se, sw) %>% as.matrix(),
  X = cbind(rep(1, nrow(d)), d$enso)
)
```

Now we can fit the model with `cmdstanr`

```r
tmp = write_stan_file(model_code)

model = cmdstan_model(tmp)

fit = model$sample(model_data )
```

## The Fit

Here are the predictions with associated 95% credible intervals

[image]

This may not look like a great fit, but remember we are comparing the estimated mean with the observed data.  Let's take a look at prediction intervals

[image]

Many of the observed data fall within the 95% posterior predictive interval.  That is a good sign, but not completely abdicating of any criticism.  We might need to think of ways to check the model which are not available to me because I don't have the necessary domain expertise on your problem.  We could also check that the predictions sum to $N_{total,i}$ at each time step, but this is unnecessary because the model forces this to be the case.

This answer is meant to demonstrate how one might fit such a model to satisfy your constraints.  In reality, much thought should be put into model criticism and model priors before using such a model.

Comment: Thank you so much for your perspective. I'm not familiar with stan, but I get errors for chains 1-4: "Chain 1 Exception: variable does not exist; processing stage=data initialization; variable name=X; base type=double (in '/var/folders/yh/r4s4cbtx203cyv5dc6cmx68h0000gn/T/RtmpzG9yfj/model-17c1d3ba85b3e.stan', line 5, column 0 to column 15)
Warning: Chain 1 finished unexpectedly!" and "All chains finished unexpectedly! Use the $output(chain_id) method for more information." and "No chains finished successfully. Unable to retrieve the fit."

Comment: @Zacharyj7 Sorry, that is my fault.  I've edited my code and it should work now.  There is a lot to learn about Stan and Bayesianism before taking this approach, but if you are willing to go down that rabbit hole then the Stan manual is a great place to start.

Comment: thank you. I will check your framework. I may have figured out a solution. I have tried implementing support vector regression for each region, and when I sum up the four regions, I get a pretty good model. It seems like the SVR method is sensitive to the nonlinearities in my data. I am still looking at that, and I will look at your suggestions also. I will edit or answer soon. Thanks.